# How to call other constructors when re-rendering with setState in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor

I have these constructors in a component.
Idea here is to have button with an onClick attribute and when the button is clicked the onItemClick() functions invokes which if the right button is clicked increments this.state.index by 1.

The problem here is that the state changes but other constructors do not get called again so nothing changes in the component.

Question is how do I call those constructors every time the state changes? Or how should I rewrite the code so the logic behind it stays, meaning that with every state change I get all the new information which depends on the state?

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      index: 1,
    }
    this.currentQ = data[this.state.index]
    this.answers = Object.values(this.currentQ.answers).map((item, index) => {
      return <button onClick={() => this.onItemClick(index)}>{item}</button>
    })
  }
```

EDIT: providing the full code of component below. Thank you for the answers!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {data} from './input.js';


class Card extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      index: 1,
    }
    this.currentQ = data[this.state.index]
    this.answers = Object.values(this.currentQ.answers).map((item, index) => {
      return <button onClick={() => this.onItemClick(index)}>{item}</button>
    })
  }

  onItemClick = (index) => {
    let rightAnswer = this.currentQ.rightAnswer
    let userGuess = Object.keys(this.currentQ.answers)[index]

    rightAnswer === userGuess ? this.setState({index: this.state.index += 1}) : console.log('false')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.currentQ.engWord}</h2>
        {this.answers}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Card;
```

Comment: please add `onItemClick function` and code where othere component you want  to render

Comment: I edited the question with all the code.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor only called once and shouldn't contain any side effect or view computations in it. Every time the state changes `render()` function gets called so you better put `answers` there. Regarding `currentQ` it is not exactly clear from the code but **maybe** it should be part of the state. If it changes a lot and component view is dependent on it it probably is. To decide better what should be part of your component state see [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).
Here is a great diagram of react component lifecycle by Dan Abramov[image: diagram]

Answer (score 1):

From the limited code provided, it seems like @balabis wants to just compute some class members based on state change. So `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method would be a good place to do so.

Code

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  this.currentQ = data[this.state.index]
  this.answers = Object.values(this.currentQ.answers).map((item, index) => {
    return <button onClick={() => this.onItemClick(index)}>{item}</button>
  })
}
```

Note: `componentDidUpdate` is not called for the initial render. For more - 
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **componentShouldMount(){}** function and try to update in this. Even I faced same problem but this way it worked for me. And don't set value directly, use **setState()** - I worked **Mobx**.